# Error running pgAdmin3.exe in Windows Virtual PC XP Mode with PostgreSQL 8.2

Tags: windows, postgresql, virtual-machine, postgresql-8.2, windows-virtual-pc

I've been having trouble figuring out why I can't get pgAdmin GUI to run after I've installed PostgreSQL 8.2 successfully with all the default options. A few things that I've tried is to add in any missing DLLs (MSJAVA.dll) after running Dependency Walker on the exe file, updating the Windows XP to the latest update on the Windows Virtual PC VM, turning off my firewall, reinstalling PostgreSQL, but to no avail. I'm still getting this same error:

```
C:\PostgreSQL\8.2\bin\pgAdmin3.exe 
This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. 
Reinstalling the application may fix the problem
```

I've read to make sure that the version of PostgreSQL is compatible with XP, and that people have successfully got it to work on a VM. I can't seem to figure out why this is not working out for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: [Postgres 8.2 is long dead and forgotten. Update to a modern version.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Plus, you did not show the version of pgAdmin.

Comment: Totally agree. PostgreSQL is the *very first* release with native Windows support. It had a number of issues. It was released in early 2006. Why on earth would you use it instead of something current?